# exbir texto de acordo com a saida do campo váriavel

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou criando uma publicação de post type com ***Advanced Custom Fields***.  Gostaria que em determinada linha, fosse exibida o texto *"Secretaria"* quando o campo `the_field('contratante')` estivesse em uso... quando for `the_field('setor02')` a palavra não seria mostrada.

```php
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    echo '<h4 class="titulos-widget-internos">'; echo 'Dados do Contrato de Número '; the_title(); echo '</h4>';
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>Origem: <strong>'; the_field('origem'); echo '</strong></li>';
    echo '<li>Contratante: <strong> Secretaria de '; the_field('contratante'); echo '</strong></li>';
    echo '<li>Contratada(o): <strong>'; the_field('contratadao'); echo '</strong></li>';
    echo '<li>Valor: <strong> R$ '; the_field('valor'); echo '</strong></li>';
    echo '<li>Início da vigência: <strong>'; the_field('inicio_da_vigencia'); echo '</strong></li>';
    echo '<li>Fim da vigência: <strong>'; the_field('fim_da_vigencia'); echo '</strong></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<p class="objeto">'; echo 'Objeto: '; the_field('objeto'); echo'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<a class="botao-padrao" href="'; the_field('contrato_original');  echo '"'; 
    echo 'target="_blank" role="button">Baixar arquivo</a>'; 
    //mh_after_post_content();
    //comments_template();
endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Branco, você quer que o texto "Contratante: Secretaria de:..." suma quando o the_field('setor02') tiver algum valor diferente de nada e que ele apareça se existir e se o the_field('setor02') não existir, é isso? ou você quer adicionar uma linha nova Só com a palavra secretaria se as condições que eu disse forem satisfeitas?

Answer (score -1):

Tem muito tempo que não trabalho com WP e seus plugins. Mas usando a lógica no seu caso, eu usaria um `if` pra verificar se o campo existe, então atualizaria o valor do `the_field` acrescentando a palavra que você deseja. Pesquisando no site do plugin, eu vi que existe uma função chamada `update_field` para atualizar o valor. Então ficaria assim:

```
if (the_field('contratante')) {

    update_field('contratante', "Secretaria de " . the_field('contratante'));
}
```

Então o `the_field('contratante')` irá exibir o valor com a palavra antes.

Edit: o `if` acima entraria logo abaixo do loop `while`.

Answer (score -1):

Olha só, tu poderia fazer uma estrutura if...

Não sei se esse é o caso!

```html
<?php 
   
if( get_field( 'setor02' ) ) {
 echo "";
} else {
 echo '<li>Contratante: <strong> Secretaria de '; the_field('contratante'); echo '</strong></li>';
}

?>
```